# Parsing an NSString with TouchXML?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, touchxml

I am trying to parse thE following string that i receive from my WebService using SOAP..
Since i am not able to parse the data i receive from my web service( of which i have no idea why.. please take a look here [parsing XML using Soap Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223547/parsing-an-xml-using-soap-web-services))  i am converting the data to an NSString and then using TOUCHXML to parse the string

```
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                    length:[webData length] 
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the string that i get is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<s:Body>

<GetCategoryResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

<GetCategoryResult>

<Root>

<Record>

<catid>1</catid><catname>Hi</catname><catlogo>http://10.25.4.49/monsoonstore/Category/50X50.GIF</catlogo>

</Record>

</Root>

</GetCategoryResult>

</GetCategoryResponse>

</s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
```

since i am not able to get any parser to read the NSData i get from webservice i convert the above string to the following (ie. the exact xml i needed)

```
<Root><Record><catid>1</catid><catname>Hi</catname><catlogo>http://10.25.4.49/monsoonstore/Category/50X50.GIF</catlogo></Record></Root>

CXMLDocument *doc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:check options:0 error:nil];



  NSArray *items = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Root" error:nil];




for (CXMLElement *item in items) 

{


NSLog(@"Root");

    NSArray *titles = [item elementsForName:@"Record"];

for(CXMLElement *title in titles) 
{
    NSLog(@"Record");

     break;
}

 NSArray *categories = [item elementsForName:@"catid"];

    for(CXMLElement *category in categories)
    {
        NSLog(@"catid");

        break;
    }


NSArray *artists = [item elementsForName:@"catname"];

    for(CXMLElement *artist in artists) 
    {
        NSLog(@"catname");

        break;
        }
.
.
.
.
```

The Root and Record logs get called while the catid never gets called.. what am i possibly doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching catid under records (and not under root) So change

```
 NSArray *categories = [item elementsForName:@"catid"];
```

to

```
NSArray *categories = [titles elementsForName:@"catid"];
```

I mean, search element catid under records, not under root.

My above code could give you compile error, as i havent worked on TouchXML, but you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSXMLParser`, As you specify you need a parser which could be created by NSData directly.

[NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) have the `initWithData` that return the NSXMLParser instance by sending NSData as parameter.

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data
```

[Parsing XML on the iPhone using NSXMLParser](http://craiggiles.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/parsing-xml-on-the-iphone/).

Comment: i did that exactly but NSXMLParser  is not able to parse the correct xml tags instead of reading **<Root>** as the first tag it reads the **<GetCategoryResult>** as the first tag and then my whole xml gets parsed even with the tags and the < > sign.. it doesn't recognize the **root** or **record** tags